# R extract values from each dataframe in multiple lists

Tags: r

I'm working in R and have the following situation:
10 lists of each 20 dataframes. The dataframes all have the same number of rows and columns.

Now I want to extract from each dataframe in each list a value. This is a value from column name 'A' from the row where column 'B' equals 3. So using the example below (which represents one data frame), I would need to extract the value 8

```
A    B    C
0    1    0
1    2    0
8    3    0
```

I want to store the values from all dataframes in a list in a vector.

I found the following code in another question on this forum

```
List <- list(c(1:3,4:5), c(4:6), c(7:9))
lapply(List, '[[', 3)  # This retuns a list with only the third element
unlist(lapply(List, '[[', 3)) # This retuns a vector with the third elements
```

So I want this to work with lists that contain dataframes, not just values.

Comment: It is not clear what you wanted.  Perhaps `lapply(lst, function(x) x$A[x$B==3])`

Comment: @akrun Indeed, this is what I wanted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We loop through the `list` of `data.frame` and extract the 'A' column values that corresponds to 'B' value of 3

```
lapply(lst, function(x) x$A[x$B==3])
```